# Discord.py bot stops working after having two @client.event or 1 @client.command and 1 @client.event

Tags: discord.py

The title pretty much explains it self but I'll explain it again.
So basically when I have 2 @client.event or 1 @client.command and 1 @client.event line in the code, the whole thing breaks except for the last block of code.
Like in my code here, the first @client.event works fine. The second one doesn't, but the third one does, now if I switch the second one and the third ones place then the second ones works but the third doesn't.

```
    import discord
    from discord.ext.commands import Bot
    from discord.ext import commands
    import asyncio
    import time
    import random
    from discord import Game
    
    Client = discord.client
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = " ")
    Clientdiscord = discord.Client()
    
    
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print('{0.user}'.format(client))
        print('Is Online')
    
    @client.command
    async def cmds(ctx):
        await ctx.send('Prefix: v!')
        await client.process_commands(ctx)
        
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.content == 'v!coin':
            variable = [
                'flip',
                'stay',
                ]
            await message.channel.send((random.choice)(variable)) 
            await client.process_commands(message)
    
    client.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: Why do you have three different clients, `Client`, `client`, and `Clientdiscord`? Also, your `command_prefix` in `client` is empty, did you mean to put `v!` instead?

Comment: Referring to the above comment, `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "v!")`

Comment: Thats something else i've been trying to figure out, everytime i put something inside of ```client =  commands.bot(command_prefix = " ")``` it doesn't work, the code doesn't break in anyway. It's like that line of code is being ignored entirely.

Comment: As for the the other 3 ```clients``` i really have no idea why i put those there, I guess i was just trying out/messing around with stuff and forgot about them since they didn't to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the `commands` framework, you should add all your commands using the `@client.commands` decorator instead of having logic in your `on_message` event handler.

If you need to handle `on_message` events for another reason (examokeL autoresponse to **non commands**), you need to call `await client.process_commands(message)` at the end of your `on_message` event handler function. It should be outside any if statements but still inside the function. **Only call `process_commands` once in your `on_message`,** and never call it inside your commands unless you know exactly what you are doing. Your `on_message` function should look something like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Do whatever here, but don't handle commands
    # If you return early, any commands in the message will be skipped
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

So instead of this:

```py
@client.command
async def cmds(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Prefix: v!')
    await client.process_commands(ctx)
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'v!coin':
        variable = [
            'flip',
            'stay',
            ]
        await message.channel.send((random.choice)(variable)) 
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

You should have something like this:

```py
@client.command()
async def cmds(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Prefix: v!')
    # Send a list of commands here or do whatever this command is supposed to do
    # Don't call client.process_commands here

@client.command()
async def coin(ctx):
    # Coinflip logic here
    # I've added the original logic you had in your question
    variable = [
        'flip',
        'stay',
    ]
    await ctx.send((random.choice)(variable))

# no @client.event or def on_message unless you need to handle raw messages
```

Also, you don't need these lines of code:

```py
Client = discord.client
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = " ")
Clientdiscord = discord.Client()
```

You can just use this:

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "v!")
```

If you are using `commands.Bot` already, you don't need another `discord.Client`.

Comment: This seems to have fixed some of the issue.
Now the terminal is detecting I'm actually trying to execute a command but gives me an error message with  " command 'coin' is not found". I also changed up the `await message.channel.send((random.choice)(variable))` with `await ctx.channel.send((random.choice)(variable))` because it wasn't detecting "message" as anything and gave me an error.

Comment: @rosewastakn Your decorators are missing brackets. They should be `@client.command()`. Also, `@client.event` **does not** need a bracket, so please do not add one

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing `await client.process_commands(message)` within your `if` statement, place it outside of it. Please review the revised code below.

```py
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.content == 'v!coin':
            variable = [
                'flip',
                'stay',
                ]
            await message.channel.send((random.choice)(variable)) 
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

Please note that you do not need to include `await client.process_commands(message)` in a command, only in your `on_message` event.

Comment: Just tried adding it but it still won't work, might it be the Python version I'm using? It's 3.10.0